# Linear Algebra. Is this question realte to combination and factorials?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am not able to understand this question and what is the entries of matrix A exactly. Question 
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: They probably mean the binomial coefficient $\binom{i+j}{i} = \frac{(i+j)!}{i!\cdot j!}$. So $a_{00} = \frac{0!}{0!\cdot 0!} = 1$, $a_{12}=\frac{3!}{1! \cdot 2!}=3$, etc.

Comment: For example with $n=3$, $$A=\begin{pmatrix}2\choose 1&3\choose 1&4\choose1\\3\choose2&4\choose 2&5\choose 2\\4\choose3&5\choose 3&6\choose 3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2&3&4\\3&6&10\\4&10&20\end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: With $\;n=2\;$ we get $$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&3\\3&6\end{pmatrix}$$ but this matrix, which is invertible doesn't fulfill $\;A^{-1}\;$ is integral, since $\;\det A\neq\pm1\;$ . The same happens with the example given by Hagen. What am I missing?

Comment: The indexing on the matrix is $0\leq i,j\leq n$, so both the matrices above are missing the first row and column. For example, $n=2$ should be $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\1&2&3\\1&3&6\end{pmatrix}$$ which has determinant 1.

Comment: Hello everybody

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this is a classical issue: these matrices are called (symmetric) "Pascal matrices", and have many properties. The fact that their determinant is an easy consequence from their Cholesky factorization (because these matrices are positive definite ).

see

web.mit.edu/18.06/www/Essays/pascal-work.pdf

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PascalMatrix.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_matrix